# Passing parameter in AngularJS url not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a value from a url call in an AngularJS template to the associated controller.

The template looks like this (the url call is near the top in the ion-item):

```html
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="watchlistitem in watchlist" href="#/app/trailer/60">
        <div class="watchlist-movie-thumb">
          <img class="movie-thumb-image" src="{{watchlistitem.picture}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-75 watchlist-title-genre-container">
          <div class="watchlist-movie-title">
            {{watchlistitem.title}}
          </div>
          <div class="watchlist-movie-genres">
            {{watchlistitem.genres}}
          </div>
        </div>


        <a class="item-icon-right" href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-trash-a" style="color:black;padding-top:40px"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="item-icon-right" href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-upload-outline" style="color:black;padding-bottom:40px;"></i>
          </a>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

In my app.js I define the route like this:

```js
  .state('app.trailer', {
    cache: false,   
    url: '/trailer/:movieId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/trailer.html',
        controller: 'TrailerCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

In the controller I do an alert to show the value of the parameter like this:

```
.controller('TrailerCtrl', function(cuesAPI, $scope, $base64, $sce, $state, $ionicModal) {

  alert("Movie ID = " + $scope.movieId);

})
```

When the alert runs it shows 'undefined' as the value. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: inject `$stateParams`, and use `$stateParams.movieId`

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed to know thanks.

Comment: try #/trailer/60, because app is not the route path but the state name